# innerHTML Not Showing

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

Recently, I posted about how to implement a variable into innerHTML to use in an online quiz. The result was that the variable was accidentally declared as a string in my code. I got rid of the quotation marks and the webpage worked again. After adding different sentences afterwards like "Your score was 11 / 11. You aced the test with full marks. Don't get too excited though, this is only the easy section." For every section of the quiz, I assigned a different score variable for each section so the user could see how well they performed after the test. For example, the easy section got it's own score variable escore, which was created by setting that variable to the current score at that particular time during the quiz. This is what I was left with:

```
function eqs() {
    var escore = score;
    if (escore < 4) {document.getElementById("sum1").innerHTML = "Well done for completing the easy questions! Your score was: " + escore + "/ 10. If you're reading this message, you got below 4 marks. Considering that this the easy section, you should've got a much higher score.";}
    if (escore > 4 && < 7) {document.getElementById("sum1").innerHTML = "Well done for completing the easy questions! Your score was: " + escore + "/ 10. You didn't get a bad score, but neither did you get a good score. If you were guessing, consider yourself lucky.";}
    if (escore > 7 && < 10) {document.getElementById("sum1").innerHTML = "Well done for completing the easy questions! Your score was: " + escore + "/ 10. You got a fairly decent score. Typically, you should get 11, but you're not far off.";}
    if (escore == 11) {document.getElementById("sum1").innerHTML = "Well done for completing the easy questions! Your score was: " + escore + "/ 10. Nice job! You aced this section with full marks! Don't get too excited though, this is only the easy section.";}
  }
```

Nothing showed up, so  I decided to add an alert that would show a popup screen whenever the function was executed telling me the value of my score. I re-tested it but once again, nothing showed up. This time, I scanned across the file to make sure that I didn't miss out on any silly mistakes. Where am I going wrong? (It would be so ironic if I wrote all of this for a silly mistake that I managed to not look at...)

Whole code (Just in case you need it):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
      body {
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
        max-width: 1160px;
      }
      .jumbotron {background-color: #ff4d4d;}
      .btn {width: 100%;}
    </style>
    <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();});
      var score = 0;
      var seconds = 0;
      function add1() {score += 1};
      function add2() {score += 2};
      function add3() {score += 3};
      function eqs() {
        var escore = score;
        alert(" + escore + ");
        if (escore < 4) {document.getElementById("sum1").innerHTML = "Well done for completing the easy questions! Your score was: " + escore + "/ 10. If you're reading this message, you got below 4 marks. Considering that this the easy section, you should've got a much higher score.";}
        if (escore > 4 && < 7) {document.getElementById("sum1").innerHTML = "Well done for completing the easy questions! Your score was: " + escore + "/ 10. You didn't get a bad score, but neither did you get a good score. If you were guessing, consider yourself lucky.";}
        if (escore > 7 && < 10) {document.getElementById("sum1").innerHTML = "Well done for completing the easy questions! Your score was: " + escore + "/ 10. You got a fairly decent score. Typically, you should get 11, but you're not far off.";}
        if (escore == 11) {document.getElementById("sum1").innerHTML = "Well done for completing the easy questions! Your score was: " + escore + "/ 10. Nice job! You aced this section with full marks! Don't get too excited though, this is only the easy section.";}
      } 
    </script>
    <title>Year 7 English Quiz - Are you smarter than an 11 year old?</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
   <h1>Year 7 English Quiz - Are you smarter than an 11 year old?</h1><hr>
   <h3>Rules: (Read before playing)</h3>
   <p>'-' Means fill in the blank with a word</p>
   <p>'|' Means fill in the blank with a phrase</p>
   <p>'+' Means complete the word</p>
   <p>There are 33 questions in this quiz.</p>
   <p>By hitting the timer to the bottom, you can challenge yourself and see how quick you could complete the quiz.</p>
   <p>11 will be a set of easy questions, another 11 will be a set of medium questions and the last 11 will be hard / or virtually impossible for a Year 7 to figure out.</p>
      <p>These difficulty levels only apply to Year 7s. A hard question could be simple to you.</p>
   <p>Have fun and don't get mad if you don't pass the test. If you fail, then that doesn't necessarily bad at English!</p>
   <p>Don't click a button two times during a quiz unless you want to mess everything up. But I know you're probably a rebel.</p>
   <p>Scroll down after each question, as some may not show on your screen and will be below</p>
   <p>At the end, your points will be tallied up. Through hard, you will receive negative points for answering a question incorrectly.</p>
   <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="stopwatch">Stopwatch</button>
   <span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q1" id="disableoc"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Chill Out M8">Just get to the questions already!</a></button></span><hr>
   <div id="q1" class="collapse">
  <h1>Easy Questions:</h1><br>
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 1: When is _ birthday?</h1></div>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q2">Answer 1: Your</button>
  <button onclick="minus1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q2">Answer 2: You're</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q2" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 2: +ranky</h1></div>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q3">Answer 1: Kranky</button>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q3">Answer 2: Cranky</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q3" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 3: Spot the word class that doesn't exist.</h1></div>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q4">Answer 1: Determiner</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q4">Answer 2: Verb</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q4">Answer 3: Noun</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q4">Answer 4: Preposition</button>
        <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q4">Answer 5: Proverb</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q4">Answer 6: Adjective</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q4" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 4: It's - cats and dogs.</h1></div>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q5">Answer 1: Pouring</button>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q5">Answer 2: Raining</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q5" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 5: +yclone</h1></div>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q6">Answer 1: Cyclone</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q6">Answer 2: Syclone</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q6" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 6: I - cheeseburger.</h1></div>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q7">Answer 1: Haz</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q7">Answer 2: Have</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q7">Answer 3: Has a</button>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q7">Answer 4: Have a</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q7" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 7: Find the tense of the following sentence: I located my nearest barber.</h1></div>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q8">Answer 1: Present</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q8">Answer 2: Simple</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q8">Answer 3: Continuous</button>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q8">Answer 4: Past</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q8">Answer 5: Future</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q8" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 8: - the remote control.</h1></div>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q9">Answer 1: Gimme</button>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q9">Answer 2: Give me</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q9">Answer 3: Gave me</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q9" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 9: What is the closest definition to a synonym?</h1></div>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q10">Answer 1: A word used to describe a verb</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q10">Answer 2: A group of words that acts in the same way as a participle</button><br>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q11">Answer 3: A word that is similar if not identical to another word</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q10" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 10: What is the closest definition to a noun phrase?</h1></div>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q11">Answer 1: Answer 2 but the noun *must* be either a subject or object</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q11">Answer 2: A phrase with 1 or more noun(s) in it</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q11">Answer 3: A noun that also acts a phrase</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q11" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 11: The he was entirely - in frozen carbonite.</h1></div>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#eqsummary" onclick="eqs()">Answer 1: Encasted</button>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#eqsummary" onclick="eqs()">Answer 2: Encapsulated</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#eqsummary" onclick="eqs()">Answer 3: Capsulated</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#eqsummary" onclick="eqs()">Answer 4: Capered</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="eqsummary" class="collapse">
     <div class="jumbotron"><p id="sum1"></p></div>
   </div>
 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I kept on reading all of your comments, none of them seemed to work too well... Either nothing showed up or it only showed up once. Because of this, I decided to get rid of the score function and instead tell the user what accumulative score they had in each section. I tested it again and it showed 0 / 0 but when I reloaded the page, I finished the quiz and I still got 0 / 0. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd and 3rd if statements are wrong. You must reference your variable on both sides of && operator.

Comment: I have added the escore variable in just as you asked, but still nothing is showing up.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working snippet. It works like you requested.

Please try it out ;)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
      body {
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
        max-width: 1160px;
      }
      .jumbotron {background-color: #ff4d4d;}
      .btn {width: 100%;}
    </style>
    <title>Year 7 English Quiz - Are you smarter than an 11 year old?</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
   <h1>Year 7 English Quiz - Are you smarter than an 11 year old?</h1><hr>
   <h3>Rules: (Read before playing)</h3>
   <p>'-' Means fill in the blank with a word</p>
   <p>'|' Means fill in the blank with a phrase</p>
   <p>'+' Means complete the word</p>
   <p>There are 33 questions in this quiz.</p>
   <p>By hitting the timer to the bottom, you can challenge yourself and see how quick you could complete the quiz.</p>
   <p>11 will be a set of easy questions, another 11 will be a set of medium questions and the last 11 will be hard / or virtually impossible for a Year 7 to figure out.</p>
      <p>These difficulty levels only apply to Year 7s. A hard question could be simple to you.</p>
   <p>Have fun and don't get mad if you don't pass the test. If you fail, then that doesn't necessarily mean you're bad at English!</p>
   <p>Don't click a button two times during a quiz unless you want to mess everything up. But I know you're probably a rebel.</p>
   <p>Scroll down after each question, as some may not show on your screen and will be below</p>
   <p>At the end, your points will be tallied up. Through hard, you will receive negative points for answering a question incorrectly.</p>
   <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="stopwatch">Stopwatch</button>
   <span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q1" id="disableoc"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Chill Out M8">Just get to the questions already!</a></button></span><hr>
   <div id="q1" class="collapse">
  <h1>Easy Questions:</h1><br>
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 1: When is _ birthday?</h1></div>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q2">Answer 1: Your</button>
  <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q2">Answer 2: You're</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q2" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 2: +ranky</h1></div>
  <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q3">Answer 1: Kranky</button>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q3">Answer 2: Cranky</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q3" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 3: Spot the word class that doesn't exist.</h1></div>
  <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q4">Answer 1: Determiner</button>
  <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q4">Answer 2: Verb</button>
  <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q4">Answer 3: Noun</button>
        <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q4">Answer 4: Preposition</button>
        <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q4">Answer 5: Proverb</button>
        <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q4">Answer 6: Adjective</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q4" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 4: It's - cats and dogs.</h1></div>
  <button  onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q5">Answer 1: Pouring</button>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q5">Answer 2: Raining</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q5" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 5: +yclone</h1></div>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q6">Answer 1: Cyclone</button>
  <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q6">Answer 2: Syclone</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q6" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 6: I - cheeseburger.</h1></div>
  <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q7">Answer 1: Haz</button>
  <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q7">Answer 2: Have</button>
  <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q7">Answer 3: Has a</button>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q7">Answer 4: Have a</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q7" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 7: Find the tense of the following sentence: I located my nearest barber.</h1></div>
  <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q8">Answer 1: Present</button>
  <button  onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q8">Answer 2: Simple</button>
  <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q8">Answer 3: Continuous</button>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q8">Answer 4: Past</button>
  <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q8">Answer 5: Future</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q8" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 8: - the remote control.</h1></div>
  <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q9">Answer 1: Gimme</button>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q9">Answer 2: Give me</button>
  <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q9">Answer 3: Gave me</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q9" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 9: What is the closest definition to a synonym?</h1></div>
  <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q10">Answer 1: A word used to describe a verb</button>
  <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q10">Answer 2: A group of words that acts in the same way as a participle</button><br>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q11">Answer 3: A word that is similar if not identical to another word</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q10" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 10: What is the closest definition to a noun phrase?</h1></div>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q11">Answer 1: Answer 2 but the noun *must* be either a subject or object</button>
  <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q11">Answer 2: A phrase with 1 or more noun(s) in it</button>
  <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q11">Answer 3: A noun that also acts a phrase</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q11" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 11: The he was entirely - in frozen carbonite.</h1></div>
  <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#eqsummary">Answer 1: Encasted</button>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#eqsummary">Answer 2: Encapsulated</button>
  <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#eqsummary">Answer 3: Capsulated</button>
  <button onclick="wAnswer()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#eqsummary">Answer 4: Capered</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="eqsummary" class="collapse">
     <div class="jumbotron"><p id="sum1"></p></div>
   </div>
 </div>
 
    <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();});
      var score = 0;
      var seconds = 0;
   var qcount = 0;
   
      function add1() {
  score++;
  qcount++;
  
  if(qcount == 11) eqs(score);
   };
   
      function add2() {score += 2};
      function add3() {score += 3};
   
      function wAnswer() {
  qcount++;
  
  if(qcount == 11) eqs(score);
   };
   
      function eqs(score) {
        var escore = score;
        alert(" + escore + ");
        if (escore < 4) {document.getElementById("sum1").innerHTML = "Well done for completing the easy questions! Your score was: " + escore + "/ 10. If you're reading this message, you got below 4 marks. Considering that this the easy section, you should've got a much higher score.";}
        if (escore > 4 && escore < 7) {document.getElementById("sum1").innerHTML = "Well done for completing the easy questions! Your score was: " + escore + "/ 10. You didn't get a bad score, but neither did you get a good score. If you were guessing, consider yourself lucky.";}
        if (escore > 7 && escore < 10) {document.getElementById("sum1").innerHTML = "Well done for completing the easy questions! Your score was: " + escore + "/ 10. You got a fairly decent score. Typically, you should get 11, but you're not far off.";}
        if (escore == 11) {document.getElementById("sum1").innerHTML = "Well done for completing the easy questions! Your score was: " + escore + "/ 10. Nice job! You aced this section with full marks! Don't get too excited though, this is only the easy section.";}
      } 
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have added the escore variable in just as you asked, but still nothing is showing up.

Comment: Notice: put your script at the bottom of your body, sometimes the script won't run if you place it in the head. Second: in the last question (11) you try 2 `onclick` events in 1 html tag. I don't think this is possible, as it runs the add first, but never the eqs.

Comment: Thanks for all of the recommendations but I tried everything, but the only change that it made was make the window pop up.

Comment: At least it's getting somewhere, plus it is best to not do 2 onclick functions in 1 html tag, maybe check what I edited in the post ^

Comment: By the way, did by any chance pop up a window with `+ escore +`?

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea get your html validated, I saw 3 errors, which of 1 I already mentioned.

Comment: Everything is acting so inconsistent for me. I added the qcount function. The first time, I thought we were getting somewhere. The innerHTML popped up and so did the alert, but it said that I got 0, even though I knew that I got 10 / 11. I tried it again, but this time nothing showed up. I tried again and nothing showed up again. I transferred the file to myself via email to a different computer and the same result showed once I had loaded it up. The score read 0 and the second time, nothing was there. Because of this, I'm quite sure that it's not just my computer.

Comment: Are you sure you also enclosed your score with the `;`?

Comment: Yes I have, check the reply I made on my question

Comment: As I kept on reading all of your comments, none of them seemed to work too well... Either nothing showed up or it only showed up once. Because of this, I decided to get rid of the score function and instead tell the user what accumulative score they had in each section. I tested it again and it showed 0 / 0 but when I reloaded the page, I finished the quiz and I still got 0 / 0. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I made a full snippet which works. Just test the snippet and you'll see

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, you need to do comparison like this `if (escore > 4 && escore < 7)`. You also need to execute this function by calling it. Your `<p id="sum1"></p>`'s parent container with id `#eqsummary` has `collapse` class, so it will be hidden.

Instead of redeclaring `escore` inside `eqs` function you could pass `score` to it, this would make your function a bit modular.

I guess your code still in progress, but here are the solution of the problem in your question

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var score = 0;
 var seconds = 0;
 
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

 function add1() {score += 1;}
 function add2() {score += 2;}
 function add3() {score += 3;}
 
 function eqs(escore) {
  var sumContainer = document.getElementById("sum1");

        if (escore < 4) {
   sumContainer.innerHTML = "Well done for completing the easy questions! Your score was: " + escore + "/ 10. If you're reading this message, you got below 4 marks. Considering that this the easy section, you should've got a much higher score.";
  }
        if (escore > 4 && escore < 7) {
   sumContainer.innerHTML = "Well done for completing the easy questions! Your score was: " + escore + "/ 10. You didn't get a bad score, but neither did you get a good score. If you were guessing, consider yourself lucky.";
  }
        if (escore > 7 && escore < 10) {
   sumContainer.innerHTML = "Well done for completing the easy questions! Your score was: " + escore + "/ 10. You got a fairly decent score. Typically, you should get 11, but you're not far off.";
  }
        if (escore === 11) {
   sumContainer.innerHTML = "Well done for completing the easy questions! Your score was: " + escore + "/ 10. Nice job! You aced this section with full marks! Don't get too excited though, this is only the easy section.";
  }
      } 
 
add1();
add2();
add3();
eqs(score);
   
});
```

```css
body{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    max-width: 1160px;
  }
.jumbotron {background-color: #ff4d4d;}
.btn {width: 100%;}

#eqsummary div{
 border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Year 7 English Quiz - Are you smarter than an 11 year old?</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
   <h1>Year 7 English Quiz - Are you smarter than an 11 year old?</h1><hr>
   <h3>Rules: (Read before playing)</h3>
   <p>'-' Means fill in the blank with a word</p>
   <p>'|' Means fill in the blank with a phrase</p>
   <p>'+' Means complete the word</p>
   <p>There are 33 questions in this quiz.</p>
   <p>By hitting the timer to the bottom, you can challenge yourself and see how quick you could complete the quiz.</p>
   <p>11 will be a set of easy questions, another 11 will be a set of medium questions and the last 11 will be hard / or virtually impossible for a Year 7 to figure out.</p>
      <p>These difficulty levels only apply to Year 7s. A hard question could be simple to you.</p>
   <p>Have fun and don't get mad if you don't pass the test. If you fail, then that doesn't necessarily bad at English!</p>
   <p>Don't click a button two times during a quiz unless you want to mess everything up. But I know you're probably a rebel.</p>
   <p>Scroll down after each question, as some may not show on your screen and will be below</p>
   <p>At the end, your points will be tallied up. Through hard, you will receive negative points for answering a question incorrectly.</p>
   <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="stopwatch">Stopwatch</button>
   <span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q1" id="disableoc"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Chill Out M8">Just get to the questions already!</a></button></span><hr>
   <div id="q1" class="collapse">
  <h1>Easy Questions:</h1><br>
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 1: When is _ birthday?</h1></div>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q2">Answer 1: Your</button>
  <button onclick="minus1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q2">Answer 2: You're</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q2" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 2: +ranky</h1></div>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q3">Answer 1: Kranky</button>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q3">Answer 2: Cranky</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q3" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 3: Spot the word class that doesn't exist.</h1></div>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q4">Answer 1: Determiner</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q4">Answer 2: Verb</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q4">Answer 3: Noun</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q4">Answer 4: Preposition</button>
        <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q4">Answer 5: Proverb</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q4">Answer 6: Adjective</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q4" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 4: It's - cats and dogs.</h1></div>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q5">Answer 1: Pouring</button>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q5">Answer 2: Raining</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q5" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 5: +yclone</h1></div>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q6">Answer 1: Cyclone</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q6">Answer 2: Syclone</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q6" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 6: I - cheeseburger.</h1></div>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q7">Answer 1: Haz</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q7">Answer 2: Have</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q7">Answer 3: Has a</button>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q7">Answer 4: Have a</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q7" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 7: Find the tense of the following sentence: I located my nearest barber.</h1></div>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q8">Answer 1: Present</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q8">Answer 2: Simple</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q8">Answer 3: Continuous</button>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q8">Answer 4: Past</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q8">Answer 5: Future</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q8" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 8: - the remote control.</h1></div>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q9">Answer 1: Gimme</button>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q9">Answer 2: Give me</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q9">Answer 3: Gave me</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q9" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 9: What is the closest definition to a synonym?</h1></div>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q10">Answer 1: A word used to describe a verb</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q10">Answer 2: A group of words that acts in the same way as a participle</button><br>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q11">Answer 3: A word that is similar if not identical to another word</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q10" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 10: What is the closest definition to a noun phrase?</h1></div>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q11">Answer 1: Answer 2 but the noun *must* be either a subject or object</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q11">Answer 2: A phrase with 1 or more noun(s) in it</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#q11">Answer 3: A noun that also acts a phrase</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="q11" class="collapse">
  <div class="jumbotron"><h1 class="question">Question 11: The he was entirely - in frozen carbonite.</h1></div>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#eqsummary" onclick="eqs()">Answer 1: Encasted</button>
  <button onclick="add1()" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#eqsummary" onclick="eqs()">Answer 2: Encapsulated</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#eqsummary" onclick="eqs()">Answer 3: Capsulated</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#eqsummary" onclick="eqs()">Answer 4: Capered</button><hr>
   </div>
   <div id="eqsummary">
     <div class="jumbotron"><p id="sum1"></p></div>
   </div>
 </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
  </body>
</html>
```

Learn more about JavaScript comparison operators. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators